# How to fetch data from multidimensional array in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello my Database looks like this:

[image: Database screenshot]

```
"delivery_pincode": [
      {
        "item_id": "106380730",
        "item_text": "560074"
      },
      {
        "item_id": "119323097",
        "item_text": "562164"
      },
      {
        "item_id": "126726811",
        "item_text": "560050"
      },
      {
        "item_id": "129564907",
        "item_text": "560115"
      }
]
```

Provided in the image and I want to fetch data in which I have added code

```
.where("delivery_pincode","array-contains-any" , pincode)
```

where pincode is "560074" so the result is giving empty array .
I have also tried with code

```
.where("delivery_pincode","array-contains-any" , [item_text: "560074"])
```

which is again giving empty array . any solution to fetch data based on item_text's pincode ?

Comment: Are you using Firestore or Realtime Database? Your question indicates the former, but the tags say the latter.

Comment: firestore database

Answer (score 0):

The `array-contains` and `array-contains-any` operators check whether the value you passed matches a complete item in the array; they can't be used to match a subset of an item.

So with your current data structure, you will have to use this query:

```
.where("delivery_pincode","array-contains", {"item_id": "106380730",item_text: "560074"})
```

---

If you don't know all properties of the item, the common workaround to allow your use-case is to add an additional array field with just the values you *do* know, and then query on that.

So for you that would be a field `delivery_pincode_item_texts`:

```
delivery_pincode_item_texts: [
  "560074",
  "562164",
  "560050",
  "560115"
]
```

You can then query that with:

```
.where("delivery_pincode_item_texts","array-contains-any", ["560074"])
```

or

```
.where("delivery_pincode_item_texts","array-contains", "560074")
```