# Is it OK to store objects and objects' ids in separate fields in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have collection of `chats` and I want to search through this collection by chat's members. Collection looks like:

```
{
 ...
 owner: 'user-123',
 members: ['user-123', 'user-456'].
 membersData: [{
  id: 'user-123',
  name: 'Jack'
 },
 {
  id: 'user-456',
  name: 'Jane'
 }
 ]
 ...
}
```

The reason of this that I can't search by members' ids using `array-contains` if members are objects. Is this solution OK? I have a very small experience in firebase (and noSQL databases generally) so may be there are best practices for this type of tasks?

Comment: You can search by objects but only using all the data. I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that is completely acceptable an in fact the idiomatic approach if you want to be able to search for just member IDs.

Also see:

- [Firestore - query where filter of object in array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374452/firestore-query-where-filter-of-object-in-array-field/59376295#59376295)
- my answer to [How to fetch data from multidimensional array in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009918/how-to-fetch-data-from-multidimensional-array-in-firebase/72015845#72015845)